# C# SaveFileDialog Clicking cancel throws exception

Tags: c#

I have looked around at possible different ways around this issue, but haven't found something that has fixed this yet.

Everything works as normal, the `SaveFileDialog` box pops up and and you can click save no problem, if you click cancel it throws an exception.

My code is below:

```
private void createNewFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
    saveFileDialog1.FileName = "New Note"; //default file name
    saveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = ".txt"; //default file extension
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files (.txt)|*.txt"; //filter files by extension
    saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog(); //bring up the Dialog box

    if(saveFileDialog1.FileName != "")
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()))
        {
            sw.Write(textResult.Text);
        }
    }

}
```

The Line it throws the error on is this one:

```
 using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()))
```

This line where it says `textResult` is the `textbox` it is reading the text from to save to a TXT file

```
sw.Write(textResult.Text);
```

The exception it is throwing is

```
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occured in mscorlib.dll"

"Additional information: Absolute path information is required"
```

Comment: whats the exception?

Comment: Test `ShowDialog` result instead of file name: `if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == true) { using (...)... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to validate that the user actually clicked "Save" before trying to use the StreamWriter.
Also, your condition:

```
if(saveFileDialog1.FileName != "")
```

will always be true as you set the FileName property just a couple of lines above it.

Instead change to this:

```
var result = saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

if(result.HasValue && result.Value)
```

If the user clicks "Save" it will return true, if the user clicks "Cancel" it will return false and if the user closes the box, result will not have a value.

More information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd491101(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: This won't compile, since result is `bool?`, not `bool`. When user closes dialog via system menu, the result is `null`.

Comment: Would this mean that i need to remove saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog(); from the bit above?

Comment: @LukeLitherland Please see my latest edit, replace your current line of ShowDialog with: var result = saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

Answer (score 0):

instead of `if(saveFileDialog1.FileName != "")` 
try

`if(saveFileDialog1.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK`)

in this case if you click save it will procceed to streamwriter if you click cancel it will close dialog without farther actions.